# webpack Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)

Tags: webpack

I have a very simple project to test new version of `webpack` with only one js file as entry point , however whenever I ran locally `npx webpack` or `npm run build` to bundle I get this error :

```
ERROR in ./src/app.js 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "webpacktut",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.32.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.2"
  }
}
```

the **webpack.config.js**

```
 var path = require('path');

 module.exports = {
    entry: {
      App:  "./src/app.js"
    },
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
      filename: "app-fin.js"
    }
};
```

can any one please tell me what went wrong ?

Comment: That's the Unicode Replacement character, displayed when one tries to load *non*Unicode text using the wrong codepage. Any characters that don't exist in that codepage are replaced by the replacement character. The location though (1:0) means that the very first byte of the file was unexpected. How was the file saved? Was it saved with a BOM perhaps? Was it saved as UTF16 instead of UTF8? UTF8 typically *doesn't* have a BOM, while UTF16 does

Comment: Open the file in your editor and save it again as UTF8. If it's a UTF8 with a BOM, you can simply remove it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [webpack 4 - Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0) on simple JS file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52351727/webpack-4-module-parse-failed-unexpected-character-10-on-simple-js-fil)

Comment: thank you so much it did solve it